# How can I convert a string datetime column to a datetime column in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime, timestamp, date-formatting

This should be pretty simple, but I can't find the correct syntax. I have a dataframe called data and it's a little like this:

```
Id     timestamp 
A9     2020-08-10 09:05:01.000000
B9     2020-08-10 09:04:18.000000
G1     2020-04-15 11:05:08.000000
D2     2020-01-18 19:04:05.000000
F8     2020-02-12 08:04:08.000000
```

However, column timestamp is a string. How can I convert to a datetime column?

I've tried this:

```
data$timestamp_new <- as.Date(data$timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
```

and this:

```
data$timestamp_new <- as.POSIXct(data$timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
```

Both are returnign <N/A>

Comment: remove the "T" from your second `format=`, the "T" is not present in this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `%T`

```
as.Date(data$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %T")
#[1] "2020-08-10" "2020-08-10" "2020-04-15" "2020-01-18" "2020-02-12"
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Id = c("A9", "B9", "G1", "D2", "F8"), timestamp = c("2020-08-10 09:05:01.000000", 
"2020-08-10 09:04:18.000000", "2020-04-15 11:05:08.000000", "2020-01-18 19:04:05.000000", 
"2020-02-12 08:04:08.000000")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ymd_hms` from `lubridate`

```
lubridate::ymd_hms(data$timestamp)
#[1] "2020-08-10 09:05:01 UTC" "2020-08-10 09:04:18 UTC" "2020-04-15 11:05:08 UTC"
#[4] "2020-01-18 19:04:05 UTC" "2020-02-12 08:04:08 UTC"
```

If you are interested only in dates, you can wrap `as.Date` to above result.